# How to use tarantool command <cartridge replicasets join> in docker with multi container?

Tags: tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I have a test stand with Cartridge cluster.
Stand start with docker-compose (use tarantool 2.10.3 docker-image with cartridge-cli inside).

container-1:

- instance-1-1
- instance-1-2

container-2:

- instance-2-1
- instance-2-2

After starting all instances on the container-1, the BASH script execute commands:

```
sh# cartridge replicasets join --replicaset group-1 instance-1-1
sh# cartridge replicasets join --replicaset group-2 instance-1-2
```

All OK

But after starting container-2 and calling the same commands, an error occurs:

```
sh# cartridge replicasets join --replicaset group-1 instance-2-1
   • Join instance(s) instance-2-1 to replica set group-1
   ⨯ Failed to connect to Tarantool instance: Failed to dial: dial unix /opt/tarantool/tmp/run/test.instance-1-1.control: connect: no such file or directory
```

In WEB all OK, but I want use CLI for it or something like this (for automatization)

Comment: "test.instance-1-1.control: connect: no such file or directory". Shouldn't it be `test.instance-2-1.control`?

Comment: If execute on container-2 than "test.instance-1-1.control". If execute in container-1 than "Failed to get edit_topology options for joining instances: Failed to get join instances opts: Configuration for instance instance-2-1 hasn't found in instances.yml"

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the cartridge-cli only works with the local instances.yml file.
If after starting all containers, I am in the container-1 change instance.yml (adding instances from container-2) then everything works fine.
But this is a strange decision.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly noted, cartridge-cli works locally (on the host where it was running). There are plans to fix this in [tt cli](https://github.com/tarantool/tt), which is currently under development (release scheduled for 2023 Q1) to replace cartridge-cli and tarantoolctl by combining and extending their functionality.
See:
https://github.com/tarantool/tt#working-with-tt-daemon-experimental